# Query to filter out data based on two logic

Tags: mysql, query, greatest-n-per-group

This is a sample table:

```
  sample_id  |      timestamp       | p_id
============================================
    62054    |  2018-09-25 10:18:15 |  2652
    62054    |  2018-09-27 16:44:57 |  966
    62046    |  null                |  1809
    62046    |  2018-09-25 10:18:15 |  2097
```

We need to filter out unique sample_id column, but the logic is

1. IF the timestamp column **is null**, then return those null column data

   ```
       62046 | null | 1809
   ```
2. IF the timestamp column **is not null**, then return the latest timestamp column data

   ```
    62054 | 2018-09-27 16:44:57 | 966
   ```

So its great if anyone provide the sql query.

We need somethings like that,

```
WHERE
IF(
    NOT NULL = all row group by sample_id,
    row where cancelled_at is maximum,
    null column
)
```

Answer (score 0):

So we're grouping by the combination of the sample_id and wheither timestamp IS NULL. The max is returned the group. `MAX(NULL)` is `NULL` so that case is covered.

```
SELECT sample_id, MAX(timestamp)
FROM table
GROUP BY sample_id, timestamp IS NULL
```

Comment: The join back to get the `p_id`.